# Turn on angularjs on only specific DOM hierarchies?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to turn off angular interpolation from the top level of my site but re-enable it for individual elements.

I'm trying to add some angular functionality to a rather large legacy site, and it's not feasible to add `ng-non-bindable` everywhere that could possibly contain `{{bindable}}` brackets. This is especially important because the site may have `{{unparseable:er9 >-14?%(% randomness}}` within those brackets. (Angular throws a [$parse:syntax] error for that and stops parsing any of the rest of my page)

Ideally, I'd set up something like `<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-non-bindable>` on every page, and then have `<div ng-controller="myController">` on the few places that actually use angular.

So far I haven't figured out a way to do this. I looked at changing the angular parser to ignore text nodes until it sees a controller, but that seems like overkill. I also tried adding `ng-app` only to the nodes I want the app to live on, but I then have to manually bootstrap each node with the app, and I think that causes me to have multiple copies of the app running simultaneously and any singletons I was hoping for would (e.g. for cacheing) would be instantiated multiple times (unless I'm wrong about this?)

Is there a way to put `ng-app` and `ng-non-bindable` on the top level `<html>` and then manually add the divs I care about to the app?

I've set up a plunkr with a simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/antMrWmWnKXHcxklh9IY?p=preview

Comment: Have you explorered a custom directive that finds elements within the ngNonBindable, say by a CSS selector, and then runs $compile on them?

Comment: You _may_ be able to inject the same app in multiple places using angular.bootstrap with a (DI annotated) factory method returning a singleton.

Comment: @MichalCharemza: It took me a while to figure out how to do that, but it works! I've forked the original plunkr and put in the fix: http://plnkr.co/edit/2rWCy7dwJNqTShXKiLgG?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Michal Charemza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319998/michal-charemza)'s comment above led me to a working solution.

I wrote a terminal directive that compiles and attaches to the `$rootScope` each `[ng-bindable]` element in the (using jquery):

```js
app.directive('defaultNonBindable', ['$compile', '$rootScope', 
  function($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
      compile: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var bindables = $('[ng-bindable]');
        bindables.each( function() {
              var el = angular.element(this),
              compiled = $compile(el);
          compiled($rootScope);
        });
      },
      terminal: true,
    }
  }
]);
```

I then wrap each block that's angular-ified in  an ng-bindable div:

```
<div ng-bindable>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
       {{this_works}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I've forked the original plunkr with an example of it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/2rWCy7dwJNqTShXKiLgG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to configure angular in a way, that it is not looking for curly braces, but your own special syntax for interpolating.

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', []);
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
myApp.controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.value="value";
});

<div>[[value]]</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/61NwNCVB73jJcYUahzWz?p=preview)

I did not test it and there might be some side effects to it, especially for third party code, but it could be a way for managing the transition phase

regards

Comment: I thought about that, but in my site [[ is just as likely as {{, as is any other random string of characters. I need to be sure that only the divs I care about are parsed.